# Parity of the sum involving Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: binomial-coefficients, parity

How can I decide upon the parity of the expression $N_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{s=0}^k\binom{n}{s}\begin{Bmatrix}
n-s\\
k-s
\end{Bmatrix}$? Here, $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
k
\end{Bmatrix}$ denotes Stirling number of the second kind.

I checked that $N_1, N_4$ are even and $N_2,N_3,N_5,N_6$ are odd.

Answer (score 4):

$$N_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{s=0}^k\binom{n}{s}{n-s\brace k-s}=\sum_{s=0}^n\binom{n}{s}\sum_{k=s}^n{n-s\brace k-s}=\sum_{s=0}^n\binom{n}{s}\sum_{k=0}^{n-s}{n-s\brace k}
=\sum_{s=0}^n\binom{n}{s}B_{n-s}=\sum_{s=0}^n\binom{n}{s}B_{s}=B_{n+1}$$ where $B_n$ is the Bell number.  Then it says on the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) for Bell numbers that these numbers repeat the pattern odd-odd-even with period three, and gives reference for that.

Comment: You have obviously misread the question. It is $\begin{Bmatrix}
n-s\\
k-s
\end{Bmatrix}$ and not $\begin{Bmatrix}
n-s\\
n-k
\end{Bmatrix}$

Comment: @firdous-ahmad-mala you are right.

Comment: @firdous-ahmad-mala I think I have fixed it.

Comment: Gy, So nice of you.